# Validation 30000 No Type Specified for the Decimal Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

What's the best way of specifying a decimal precision without using attributes.
I just need to set it in one place for all decimal's in my Data.Models. Its tedious specifying attributes for every decimal.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int customerId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal AvailableAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add following to  the `OnModelCreating` method in the dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{         
   foreach (var property in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
                .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?)))
            {   
              property.Relational().ColumnType = "decimal(18,2)";   
            }
}
```

Comment: where does "Relational()" come from?

Comment: You should install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`  package

Comment: This answer is wrong if any of your decimal columns is not decimal(18,2). Proceed with caution...

Comment: Instead of Relational(), do property.SetColumnType("decimal(18,2)");

Answer (score 16):

For those who are struggling with the same issue on EntityFrameworkCore 6.0, this will do it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var decimalProps = modelBuilder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => (System.Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ClrType) ?? p.ClrType) == typeof(decimal));

    foreach (var property in decimalProps)
    {
        property.SetPrecision(18);
        property.SetScale(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use property.SetColumnType().

Comment: Be sure to add this _after_ defining all of your keys, relationships, etc, in the onModelCreating.

Answer (score 9):

I experienced this issu using ASP.NET CORE 5. I added the folowing code to the OnModelcreating method in the DbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)// Crée la migration
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(p => p.Prix).HasColumnType("decimal(18,4)");

    }
```

And all started working fine.

Answer (score 9):

The [Precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.precisionattribute?view=efcore-6.0) attribute can be used instead of hardcoding the decimal database type in C# code.

This:

```cs
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
```

Can be defined like this:

```cs
[Precision(18, 2)]
public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
```

Tested with EF Core 6.

Comment: See *Its tedious specifying attributes for every decimal.* Just another attribute doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Bigabdoul's answer. There are some situations that have been ignored.

For example if you have added special annotation for special fields this code doesn't care and override it.
But I have changed code as below to don't modify that fields.

Maybe you use one of these codes for a special property:

1- Use **Column(TypeName)**

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
```

2- Use **[Precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.precisionattribute?view=efcore-6.0)**

```
[Precision(18, 2)]
public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
```

3- Use **[PropertyBuilder.HasPrecision Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder.hasprecision?source=recommendations&view=efcore-7.0)**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(p => p.MyProperty).HasPrecision(18, 2);
}
```

4- Use **[PropertyBuilder.HasColumnType method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hascolumntype?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-relationalpropertybuilderextensions-hascolumntype(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-propertybuilder-system-string))**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(p => p.MyProperty).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
}
```

5- Use **[IEntityTypeConfiguration Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ientitytypeconfiguration-1?view=efcore-7.0)**

```
public class MyEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("MyEntity");
        builder.Property(x => x.MyEntity).HasPrecision(18, 2);
    }
}
```

And then

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    // Or use explicitly
    //modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MyEntityConfiguration());
}
```

All of these situations will be ignored.

But this code care about them and check if there is no related annotation, it will add it to property.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var decimalProps = modelBuilder.Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
        .Where(p => (System.Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ClrType) ?? p.ClrType) == typeof(decimal));

    foreach (var property in decimalProps)
    {
        var annotations = property.GetAnnotations();
        if (annotations.Count(x => x.Name is "Relational:ColumnType" or "Precision" or "Scale") != 0) continue;
        // Or Use this line if you use older version of C#
        // if (annotations.Count(x => x.Name == "Relational:ColumnType" || x.Name == "Precision" || x.Name == "Scale") != 0) continue;
        property.SetPrecision(18);
        property.SetScale(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
   var properties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal));
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
    }
}
```

http://jameschambers.com/2019/06/No-Type-Was-Specified-for-the-Decimal-Column/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this has been answered years ago in a few different variations, but one thing I would like to add is the ability to allow for specification on the property using the `[Precision()]` attribute for different precisions, with a fall-thru for all `decimal` properties on all entities:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Fetch all entity classes that derive from the `BaseEntity`
    var entities = typeof(BaseEntity).Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseEntity)) && !t.IsAbstract);
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        // Iterate thru the properties of the entity
        foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties())
        {
            // If decimal or nullable decimal 
            // and not using the `Precision` attribtue, define the precision
            if ((property.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) 
                    || property.PropertyType == typeof(decimal?)) 
                    && !property.GetCustomAttributes<PrecisionAttribute>().Any())
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity(entity)
                .Property(property.PropertyType, property.Name).HasPrecision(18, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```